# Is there an animal venom to which humans are naturally resistant?

Tags: human-biology, poison

Some species, no matter how poisonous or venomous, have natural predators that can withstand the poison/venom. Does human also have something similar?

This question came to me after I spent an hour observing my pet black widow and looking up related materials online. I realize that some species of wasps can neutralize the poison of the black widow naturally. Hence, I wonder if humans have something similar.

Comment: Humans are resistant to some natural compounds that can be (very) dangerous to other animals, for example caffeine and related molecules, but those are plant-based. We can tolerate doses of animal-produced toxins that are lethal to other, generally smaller, animals - for example, black widow bites are rarely fatal to humans, but can easily kill their natural prey.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you! My question aims to ask specific natural compounds that other animals/plants/etc. use as their defense mechanisms that humans can neutralize it. For example, while the black widow's venom is rarely lethal for humans due mainly to our size, we do not have something that counters it effectively. On the other hand, the yellow wasp does.

Comment: what do you mean by resistant? death? damage? what kind of damage? Humans are not resistant to caffeine, nicotine or ethanol (for example) but we do not die from small dosages. Same goes for spider bites, snake stings etc. Even too much water can kill humans.

Comment: @Hachiloni no, we are not completely *resistant* to the things you mentioned, but we have functioning biochemical pathways that can metabolize those compounds. I was thinking specifically of the effect of caffeine on dogs - they are much more sensitive to its effects than humans, even taking into account differences in body weight, and can be poisoned by equivalent mg/kg doses that some people consume daily via coffee or energy drinks.

Comment: @MattDMo This turns out to be a lot less clear cut than I originally thought. It seems I would need a better definition of what I mean by "resistance" as well. But I lack the background to suggest a meaningful one. I guess originally my thinking was along the line of whether humans are natural predators of some other animals. If that is so and the animals produce certain toxins, then maybe humans are immune to those toxins, just sort of a evolutionary thing.

Comment: @Paichu I think an important point you might be overlooking is that humans are *generalist* predators, not niche ones. When you have a situation like a venomous black widow spider and a venom-resistant predating wasp, typically the reason is that they both co-evolved in the same ecological niche, which is how resistance develops. There is no relationship like that with humans and any of our prey - we don't occupy a single niche, and didn't evolve to specifically feed on any one thing, therefore no venom/resistance mechanisms have developed.

Comment: no venoms I know of, but humans are highly resistant to maillard compounds, far more than any other animal.  they are toxic byproducts produced by cooking food, mostly overcooking it.